# Drag-and-Drop Issue in PySide 6: Unable to Move Window or Press Buttons on Third Screen, Works Fine in PySide 2

Tags: pyside6

How can I resolve the issue where, while dragging a window to my third screen in PySide6, I encounter a situation where I am unable to move the window or press any buttons? I can only resize it. Interestingly, this problem does not occur with PySide2, where everything works as expected.

```py
import ctypes

import win32api
import win32gui

from ctypes.wintypes import MSG, LONG

from win32con import WM_NCCALCSIZE, GWL_STYLE, WM_NCHITTEST, WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, WS_THICKFRAME, \
    WS_CAPTION, HTTOPLEFT, HTBOTTOMRIGHT, HTTOPRIGHT, HTBOTTOMLEFT, \
    HTTOP, HTBOTTOM, HTLEFT, HTRIGHT, HTCAPTION, WS_POPUP, WS_SYSMENU, WS_MINIMIZEBOX

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QHBoxLayout

class TitleBar(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self._layout = QHBoxLayout()
        button_style = "QPushButton{{border: none;outline: none;background-color: {};color: white;padding: 6px;width: " \
                       "80px;font: 16px Consolas;}}QPushButton:hover{{background-color: {};}} "

        # set size
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.setMinimumHeight(50)

        self.close_button = QPushButton("EXIT", clicked=app.exit)
        self.close_button.setStyleSheet(button_style.format('rgb(220, 0, 0)', 'rgb(240, 0, 0)'))

        self.maximize_button = QPushButton("Maximize", clicked=parent.showMaximized)
        self.maximize_button.setStyleSheet(button_style.format('rgb(25, 118, 210)', 'rgb(39, 136, 232)'))

        self.minimize_button = QPushButton("Minimize", clicked=parent.showMinimized)
        self.minimize_button.setStyleSheet(button_style.format('rgb(76, 175, 80)', 'rgb(92, 196, 96)'))

        # set background color
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QColor("#212121"))
        self.setPalette(p)

        self._layout.addStretch()
        self._layout.addWidget(self.minimize_button)
        self._layout.addWidget(self.maximize_button)
        self._layout.addWidget(self.close_button)

        self.setLayout(self._layout)


class Window(QWidget):
    BORDER_WIDTH = 5

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hwnd = self.winId().__int__()
        window_style = win32gui.GetWindowLong(self.hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(self.hwnd, GWL_STYLE, window_style | WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
                                                                  | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX )

        # Window Widgets
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self._layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self._layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.controlWidget = TitleBar(self)
        self.controlWidget.setObjectName("ControlWidget")

        # main widget is here
        self.mainWidget = QWidget()
        self.mainWidgetLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainWidgetLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainWidgetLayout)
        self.mainWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        # set background color
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QColor("#272727"))
        self.setPalette(p)

        self._layout.addWidget(self.controlWidget)
        self._layout.addWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.setLayout(self._layout)
        self.show()

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            if self.windowState() & Qt.WindowMaximized:
                margin = abs(self.mapToGlobal(self.rect().topLeft()).y())
                self.setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)
            else:
                self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        return super(Window, self).changeEvent(event)

    def nativeEvent(self, event, message):
        return_value, result = super().nativeEvent(event, message)

        # if you use Windows OS
        if event == b'windows_generic_MSG':
            msg = MSG.from_address(message.__int__())
            # Get the coordinates when the mouse moves.
            # % 65536: converted an unsigned int to int (for dual monitor issue)
            x = win32api.LOWORD(ctypes.c_long(msg.lParam).value)
            if x & 32768: x = x | -65536
            y = win32api.HIWORD(ctypes.c_long(msg.lParam).value)
            if y & 32768: y = y | -65536

            # Print x and y for debugging
            print("Mouse Coordinates: x={}, y={}".format(x, y))

            x = x - self.frameGeometry().x()
            y = y - self.frameGeometry().y()


            # Determine whether there are other controls(i.e. widgets etc.) at the mouse position.
            if self.childAt(x, y) is not None and self.childAt(x, y) is not self.findChild(QWidget, "ControlWidget"):
                if self.width() - self.BORDER_WIDTH > x > self.BORDER_WIDTH and y < self.height() - self.BORDER_WIDTH:
                    return return_value, result

            if msg.message == WM_NCCALCSIZE:
                # Remove system title
                return True, 0

            if msg.message == WM_NCHITTEST:
                w, h = self.width(), self.height()
                lx = x < self.BORDER_WIDTH
                rx = x > w - self.BORDER_WIDTH
                ty = y < self.BORDER_WIDTH
                by = y > h - self.BORDER_WIDTH
                if lx and ty:
                    return True, HTTOPLEFT
                if rx and by:
                    return True, HTBOTTOMRIGHT
                if rx and ty:
                    return True, HTTOPRIGHT
                if lx and by:
                    return True, HTBOTTOMLEFT
                if ty:
                    return True, HTTOP
                if by:
                    return True, HTBOTTOM
                if lx:
                    return True, HTLEFT
                if rx:
                    return True, HTRIGHT

                return True, HTCAPTION

        return QWidget.nativeEvent(self, event, message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```